# Linear Algebra Hint. Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a linear transformation $A: \mathbb{R}^{m} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$. I have to prove equivalence of 6 claims. I I couldn't prove one implication.

> $$|Ax - Ay| = |x - y| \Longrightarrow \langle Ax, Ay \rangle = \langle x, y \rangle$$

Any hint? I didn't want the solution.

Comment: there should be a relation between $A$ and $A^{T}$!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that from the assumptions,
$$|Ax| = |Ax - A0| = |x - 0| = |x|.$$
Fix $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^m$. Then
\begin{align*}
&|x - y|^2 = |Ax - Ay|^2 \\
\implies \, &|x|^2 + |y|^2 - 2\langle x, y\rangle = |Ax|^2 + |Ay|^2 - 2\langle Ax, Ay\rangle \\
\implies \, &2\langle x, y\rangle = 2\langle Ax, Ay\rangle.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

$$|Ax-Ay|=\sqrt{\langle Ax, Ay \rangle\langle Ax, Ay \rangle}$$